# stack dealing with recognizng string in language, java program

Tags: java, stack

SO my program is about language `L = {'w$w' : w` is a possible empty string of characters other than `$, w' = reverse(w)}`

So when something like hod$doh is fed to the parameter of isINlanguage function it should return true, but my program just stops and hangs doesnt out put anything

```
 import java.util.Stack;


 public class Stacks 
{


public static void main(String[] args){
boolean eval = isInLanguage("sod$dos");

System.out.println(eval);


}




static //   astack.createStack();
    boolean isInLanguage(String aString){
    Stack<Character> aStack = new Stack<>(); 


    int i = 0;
    char ch = aString.charAt(i);
    while (ch != '$') {
        aStack.push(ch);
        i++;
    }
    //Skip the $
    ++i;

    // match the reverse of w
    boolean inLanguage = true; // assume string is in language
    while (inLanguage && i < aString.length()) {
        char stackTop;
        ch = aString.charAt(i);;
        try {
            stackTop =  (char) aStack.pop();
            if (stackTop == ch) {
                i++;
            } else {
                // top of stack is not ch(Charecter do not match)
                inLanguage = false; // reject string

            }
        } catch (StackException e) {
            // aStack.poo() failed, astack is empty (first, half of Stirng
            // is short than second half)

            inLanguage = false;
        }
    }

    if (inLanguage && aStack.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: This cast is not necessary: stackTop =  (char) aStack.pop();

Comment: without the cast,i get
'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to char

 at Stacks.isInLanguage(Stacks.java:33)
 at Stacks.main(Stacks.java:6)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not resetting the `ch` inside the `while` loop to the next character:

```
while (ch != '$') {
    aStack.push(ch);
    i++;
    ch = aString.charAt(i);   // Add this
}
```

Also, inside the `try` block, the cast is not necessary. The assignment:

```
stackTop =  (char) aStack.pop();
```

... is better written as:

```
stackTop = aStack.pop();
```

---

BTW, you are really complicating your task, by using `boolean` variable, and `try-catch` blocks. Don't let the `stack.pop()` throw any exception. Rather, pop an element only if stack is not empty. Also, you can directly return as soon as you find the string doesn't matches the required language, so there is no need to boolean variable.

I would modify your method as:

```
static boolean isInLanguage(String aString){
    Stack<Character> aStack = new Stack<>(); 

    int i = 0;
    char ch;

    // This is simplified way to write your first while loop
    // Read a character, move the index further, and test, all in single statement
    while ((ch = aString.charAt(i++)) != '$') {
        aStack.push(ch);
    }

    // Iterate till the stack is not empty
    while (!aStack.isEmpty()) {
       // Get next character in string, and pop an element from stack
       // If they are not equal, return false
        if (aString.charAt(i++) != aStack.pop()) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // If we reach here, means stack is empty. Test if the index `i` has reached end of the string.
    // If it reached the end of the string, return true, else return false (because there are still some characters to be processed).
    return i == aString.length();
}
```

`aString.charAt(i++)` will get the character at index `i`, and increment `i` thereafter.

Comment: wow Thanks rohit, easy solution +1 !

Comment: @ClearMist Check out the really simplified code to do the task. It is much simpler to proceed without extra boolean variable, and string length check is redundant really.

Comment: the cast is needed otherwise i get this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to char

 at Stacks.isInLanguage(Stacks.java:33)
 at Stacks.main(Stacks.java:6)

Comment: @ClearMist With `Stack<Character>`, you won't get that error.

Comment: that is what i got after removing the cast, without implementing yours, i have to use my own code sorry